# error from qt unresolved C2019

Tags: c++, qt, slots

I write in header file private slots and the compiler gives an error:

`d:\qtproject\new123\mainwindow.h:31: error: C2059: syntax error : 'public'`

Please help me. I changed to public but no difference.When I clear 'public/private slots' no error comes , but writes 
loading D:\Qtproject\new123\debug\new123.exe...
QObject::connect: No such slot QPushButton::changed() in main.cpp:18
QObject::connect: No such slot QPushButton::moved() in main.cpp:27

```
mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
  private slots:
    void changed();
    void moved();
    signals:
    void clicked();
  private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void moved()
{
    QPushButton a;
     a.move(100,100);
}
void changed()

{   QPushButton g;
    g.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color : white; color :blue; }");
}

main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;

    QPushButton s("Change Color", &w);
    s.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color : white; color :pink; }"
                    "QPushButton:pressed { color: blue; }");
    QObject::connect(&s, SIGNAL(clicked()), &s, SLOT(changed()));
    QPushButton d("Quit", &w);
    d.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color : white; color :black; }");
    QObject::connect(&d, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
    d.move(100,0);
    QPushButton f("Move Button", &w);
    f.move(200,0);
    f.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color : white; color :green; }");

    QObject::connect(&f, SIGNAL(clicked()), &f, SLOT(moved()));

    w.show();

    return a.exec();

}
```

Comment: please help, I started study QT  and need your help

Comment: Relevant code please.

Comment: #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>



namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
void changed();
void moved();
signals:
void clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: The error message talks about a problem on line 31. The snippet above doesn't have 31 lines.

Comment: Help us help you. Post a minimal but complete program that demonstrates the problem. Show us all the error messages.

Comment: before #endif is the 31th line. when I clear ''public slots'' no error comes, but writes

Comment: I copied the whole code, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn C++ before you learn Qt.

You declare `moved()` and `changed()` as methods of `MainWindow`, but then define them as free functions in the source file.  You then attempt to connect the `QPushButton::clicked()` to these slots, but tell the `connect(..)` method that the slots belong to the `QPushButton` instead of `MainWindow`.

In your `moved()` and `changed()` functions you create   a `QPushButton` in each, but don't give them a parent or add them to a layout (so they won't be visible). You also create them on the stack, so they are destroyed as the functions end.

Comment: yes I learn everything and everytime)).thank You, but I am confused, I want to create a Button, click on it and change the text color, and create other button, click on it and move it.Can You  give me an example how to do it, or code?

Comment: @kawake123 No. SO is not a software consultancy, there are enormous numbers of tutorials and examples at the Qt website (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html). You can ask a new question when have a _specific_ problem.